# golang fast alternative to memcpy

Tags: go

I have this example in C

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t dest[4];
    uint8_t src[16] = {0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14,
                       0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22,
                       0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33,
                       0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44};
 
    memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(src));

    printf("%04X %04X %04X %04X\n", dest[0], dest[1], dest[2], dest[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

and I'm migrating to golang, I don't want use C.memcpy and I'm searching for a fast alternative. This is my code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/binary"
)

func main() {
    dest := make([]uint32, 16)
    var src = []byte{0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14,
                     0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22,
                     0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33,
                     0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44}

    dest[0] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(src[0:4])
    dest[1] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(src[4:8])
    dest[2] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(src[8:12])
    dest[3] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(src[12:16])

    fmt.Printf("%04X %04X %04X %04X\n", dest[0], dest[1], dest[2], dest[3])
}
```

Can I convert an array of byte in array of uint32 with a single instruction without use C.memcpy? I tried to use copy but give error.
I know I can use this istruction

```
C.memcpy(unsafe.Pointer(&dest[0]), unsafe.Pointer(&src[0]), 16)
```

I'd like to understand if exist a valid alternative

Comment: The second approach with LittleEndian is the safest way. You can put that in a for-loop, or you can use a for-loop and shift operators to do the little endian decoding yourself. Other approaches will work around the type system and are not guaranteed to be portable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`unsafe.Pointer` is the way to bypass the Go type system, with all the caveats of using the [`unsafe` package](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe). To get the equivalent of `memcpy`, you would pass your `dest` slice to `copy` like so: https://play.golang.org/p/MFJjHhDZatl

```
copy(unsafe.Slice((*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&dest[0])), len(src)), src)
```

However, I would still make sure to run some benchmarks to ensure that your use case actually benefits from this type of optimization. Most situations can use safer methods without noticeable impact on performance.