# How to copy *C.char?

Tags: go, cgo

What's the equivalent of mempcy() for *C.char?

I have a function that will be called from C using `-buildmode=c-shared`:

```golang
myGoStr := "blabla"

//export GetString
func GetString(text *C.char) {
 memcpy(text, myGoStr)
}
```

- memory is allocated in C
- string is golang type

How can I copy the Go string to the C allocated memory behind `*C.char`?

I'm well aware of all the C.String functions (https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo#hdr-Go_references_to_C) but I don't want Go to allocate the memory, I want to work directly with a C pointer given by the C application.

The only way I found is:

```golang
cStr := C.CString(text)
C.strcpy(text, cStr)
C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cStr))
```

but it's too overkill since it involves 2 copies (`C.CString` and `C.strcpy`)

Comment: You can't copy an arbitrary string into `text`, because you don't know the extent of the `*C.char` allocation and may overflow the buffer. `C.String` doesn't allocate the memory in go, it allocates it in C. You also can't call `C.free` before returning, because that would invalidate the `cStr` pointer.

Comment: If you actually want something like `memcpy`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69816793/golang-fast-alternative-to-memcpy, but you haven't supplied enough information here to know if that is even safe to do.

Comment: @JimB "you can't" and "you shouldn't" are different. Please read again my question, your comment is literally the reason of my question. The link of your 2nd comment is completely different and uses pure go and can be done it safely.

Comment: The linked answer is "using go" because you are asking about using Go. You could of course write a helper function in C and call that but doesn't seem to be what you're asking. You can use that exact same technique to copy the bytes with no allocation in Go, and with no regard for the size of the buffer passed in. It can be as unsafe as you want it to be.

Comment: I don't mix unsafe and wrong. Nothing guarantees the underlying memory is coherent, therefore it shouldn't be correct to just take the pointer of a go type.

Comment: I don’t know what you’re arguing about here. It is not incorrect to take a pointer to a Go value (the memory layout is specified), but the suggestion has nothing to do with Go memory layout, it’s simply copying bytes from one location to another, just like you asked. It would help to address what problems you are having rather than replying with vague arguments.

Comment: As for concerns about safety or correctness, StackOverflow posts are not for you personally, they are for future readers, so comments may attempt to clarify concerns that you are aware of, but others who come across this may not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want but the thing is, either way will be unsafe — in one way or another. The reason for this is that `memcpy` *is already* unsafe (in the Go's frame of thinking) because its third argument — the number of bytes to copy — is not somehow obtained from the rest of that function's arguments (what the Go's `copy` does).

So yes, you can avoid the usual Go's `unsafe` dance to construct a slice out of your `*C.char` to pass to `copy` and have that warm cozy feeling of being safe, but then another solution — such as just calling `memcpy` directly — will anyway *rely* on the said `*C.char` to point to a memory block with enough free space to contain at least as much bytes there is in the Go's source string, plus one, and nothing guarantees that.

I mean, if you want to go this way, you can just do that:

```golang
/*
#include <string.h>

static void memcpy_from_go(char *dst, _GoString_ src)
{
    memcpy(dst, src.p, src.n);
}
*/
import "C"

const myGoStr = "blabla"

//export GetString
func GetString(text *C.char) {
    C.memcpy_from_go(text, myGoStr)
    // (!) note that no NUL terminator is placed into the destination block
}

func main() {}
```

But as there's no safeness anyway, I would argue that the analogous

```golang
func strcpyToC(dst *C.char, src string) {
    n := len(src)

    ds := unsafe.Slice((*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(dst)), n+1)

    copy(ds, src)
    ds[n] = 0
}

//export GetString
func GetString(text *C.char) {
    strcpyToC(text, myGoStr)
}
```

is just clearer and and just as unsafe.

To reiterate in other words, you cannot do memory operations with the C side from your Go side and still claim your Go side is safe.

Comment: I'll never understand all the fuss about safety. This code is still 100% safe as long as the developer makes sure there is enough memory allocated in C. If one can't make sure of that, it shouldn't even be coding. all these people obsessed with safety don't even run their apps on servers or use laptops with ECC memory... I accept this answer since it doesn't create an extra useless copy.

Comment: @Alexis, «If one can't make sure of that, it shouldn't even be coding»—I think you're just idealizing :-) You can look at a string of CVEs found even in high-profile pieces of software (or maybe even "highest"—among those developed "the usual way", that is, I'm not saying about comet lander firmware or SW controlling nuclear plants; that's another story) to see that even the best programmers introduce bugs; sometimes they creep in during refactorings etc. This is just a matter of fact which beats any theorising—like it or not. I guess I had your way of thinking but >20 years in IT affected me.

Comment: Maybe, but the context of my comment was a simple interface between C and go, not a years old complicated app written in C. I believe a normal dev can be careful for tiny simple unsafe cgo functions. (about the CVEs, I believe it's also because several devs are involved and don't necessarily know the other parts, it becomes the problem of the devs, not the safety of the code) Anyway, thanks for your answer!